# Android View.OnkeyListener вопрос

Tags: android, сборщик-мусора

Я читаю книгу по разработке игр и у меня возник вопрос по поводу метода `onKey()`,
который вызывается при нажатии клавиши с клавиатуры. [Документация.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

Этот метод получает KeyEvent, который содержит в себе информацию о нажатой клавише. У меня такой вопрос, куда девается этот KeyEvent при завершении выполнения метода? Он уничтожается сборщиком мусора, или система переиспользует созданные объекты, задавая старым новые значения, прежде чем снова отдать новому методу?

Такой вопрос у меня возник из-за того, что в книге все ивенты, полученные методом `onKey()`, записываются в массив, а если в массиве есть прошлые ивенты, прошлым задаются значения новых, чтобы избежать сбора мусора. Есть ли в этом смысл? Или правильнее было бы сохранять ссылку на объект из метода `onKey()` вместо сохранения всех значений этого объекта в cвой объект?